# DF and DU show different usage, but LSOF shows no deleted files

Tags: linux, docker, du, df, lsof

I'm running Docker daemon on an RedHat host and Docker containers are being built here on a daily basis.

After a couple of days the mount point reserved for the Docker daemon (`/var/lib/docker`) fills up, causing build processes to fail.

- Checking `df` confirms `/var/lib/docker` to use 9.2GB
- Checking `du` on `/var/lib/docker` shows around 790MB in use
- Checking `lsof` on `/var/lib/docker` shows no deleted files

This screenshot shows the for the outputs of these commands.

[image: screenshot]

Restarting the `docker.service` doesn't free up space. However, restarting the server frees up the space, and `df` and `du` show comparable usages again.

For the moment I let this server reboot every day, but I’d like to fix the root cause, not the effect of it.

Any idea what’s causing this or where to look?

Comment: Sorry you are experiencing this. But that screenshot would be more useful as copied text. Text placed in the question as a code formatted it. Please see if you can do that when you can.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, I fail to see what's the added benefit of having this output as plain text, except for accessibility reasons for the visually impaired.
I cannot reproduce this immediatly because I restarted the server which frees up this space.
The only way to reproduce is to disable automatic reboots and cause an issue for the developers again.
Can you answer my question based on the screenshot?

Comment: I cannot personally answer the question, but the reality is screenshots of text are discouraged here. Not because of issues of accessibility for visually impaired, but it is simply hard to read and — more important — the content will not be indexed for searches and will look odd on different screen sizes. Anyway, all I did was clean up your question to help you find a solution or an explanation. I do not have either of those things. This community works together to help us all help each other. Hopefully someone can come by and provide you with an answer or explanation.